# Is there some kind of JSON loader for Brunch.io the way there is in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, brunch

Using Webpack "loaders", I can "require" a JSON file using a plugin/loader. Something like,

```
var myData = require('!json!./dataFile.json');
```

This way I can access many different JSON files in my js modules without having to make http requests or manually paste the data into a js file.

Is there any plugin like this for Brunch, or a different way of obtaining the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the plugin: `npm i -S json-brunch`

Then, simply put json files into app directory and require them: require("file.json"). Done.

Comment: That's really cool! And I hope you don't mind the follow up question, but where do you put the .json? In the javascripts folder or something else? And is there some kind of raw loader as well? For instance I recently worked on a project that had a large amount of inline svg and it was nice to just require the svg instead of using an image url or something.

Comment: As i've mentioned in the answer: put it **into the `app` directory**.

Comment: As for the raw svg loader — no such thing for now. We're having it in plans though.

Comment: Hi @PaulMiller,

I finally had a chance to try this out and I simply could not get it to work. Tried it on my own config and also the Dead Simple Skeleton just like you said. Received error every time: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'data.json' from 'initialize.js`

Comment: Updated the post.